# Customize Authorization Code claims with Spring OAuth2 Authorization Server 3.2.4

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak, spring-oauth2, spring-authorization-server

I have the following flow with Keycloak and a service based on the Spring OAuth2 Authorization Server:

- Keycloak delegates auth to Spring OAuth2 Authorization Server
- Spring OAuth2 Authorization Server sends back using Authorization Grant Type request
- Keycloak sends access token to a client

The access token contains some information about Principal from Authorization Server (name and email, for example) in the `preferred_username` claim:

```json
"preferred_username":"given_name='markus',email='email01@noreply.com'"
```

But I need these data in separate claims, something like this:

```json
"given_name"="markus",
"email"="email01@noreply.com",
```

The question how to pass these data in the Authorization Grant Type request from the Authorization Server to Keycloak, so Keycloak will be able to put/pass these data in the separate claims of access token?

In Authorization Server service I have the following:

**Principal class**

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {
    private String givenName;
    private String email;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "given_name='" + givenName + '\'' +
                ",email='" + email + '\'';
    }
}
```

A value generated by `toString()` somehow appears in the `preferred_username` claim of access token in Keycloak.

**Auth provider**

```java
@Service
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider<T extends CustomAuthBean, A extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken> implements AuthenticationProvider {
    User user = this.getUserDetails();
    return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, "", getAuthorities());
}
```

**Configuration**

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
                .oidc(withDefaults());
        http
                .exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions
                        .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
                                new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"),
                                new MediaTypeRequestMatcher(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                        )
                )
                .oauth2ResourceServer((resourceServer) -> resourceServer
                        .jwt(withDefaults()));

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Please let me know if any more info is needed. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `The question how to pass these data in the Authorization Grant Type request from the Authorization Server to Keycloak, so Keycloak will be able to put/pass these data in the separate claims of access token?` why would you even do that? first of all, dont trust the client, whatever comes from the cclient can't be trusted. Second, `Authorization Grant Type` is not something you pass variables through. Its a variable that has a predefined set of valid values according to a defined specification. So your question does not even make sense.